# Pivoting data without column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Starting from an imported df from excel like that:

| Code | Material | Text | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | X222 | Model3 | 1 |
| A2 | 4027721 | Gruoup1 | 1 |
| A2 | 4647273 | Gruoup1.1 | 4 |
| A1 | 573828 | Gruoup1.2 | 1 |

I want to create a new pivot table like that:

| Code | Qty |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 2 |
| A2 | 5 |

I tried with the following command but they do not work:

```
df.pivot(index='Code', columns='',values='Qty')

df_pivot = df ("Code").Qty([sum, max])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `pivot` but `groupby`:

```
out = df.groupby('Code', as_index=False)['QTY'].sum()

# Or

out = df.groupby('Code')['QTY'].agg(['sum', 'max']).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  Code  sum  max
0   A1    2    1
1   A2    5    4
```

The equivalent code with `pivot_table`:

```
out = (df.pivot_table('QTY', 'Code', aggfunc=['sum', 'max'])
         .droplevel(1, axis=1).reset_index())
```